# Hateoas java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder

Tags: spring, rest, jsf, hateoas

I am using Hateoas feature for calling Controller's post method url. But i am getting above exception when I try to use linkTo method of ControllerLinkBuilder class as described below:

**Java class:**

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CallController{  

    public String doThis()
    {  
        ManagementResource resource = new ManagementResource();
        resource.add(linkTo(DataController.class).withRel("postData"));
        return ""; 
    }

}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "")
    public ResponseEntity<ManagementResource> postData(@RequestBody Data1 data) {
        RSResponse<Data1> response = new RSResponse<Data1>();
        response.setStatus(RSResponse.Status.SUCCESS);
        response.setData(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<ManagementResource>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

If anyone has idea about it, what I'm doing wrong here, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Think it's because you are calling the linkTo method from the \@Component  , instead it should be called from the \@Controller i suppose